# posting new user goes wrong Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Guid'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to post a new user to my database but I get this error:

> Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Guid'. Path 'personId', line 1, position 130."

This is my code:

```javascript
 newContactForm = new FormGroup({
  firstName: new FormControl(),
  lastName: new FormControl(),
  anrede: new FormControl(),
  titel: new FormControl(),
  briefanrede: new FormControl(),
  personId: new FormControl(),

 });


onSubmit(){
      console.log(this.newContactForm.getRawValue());
      this.pService.registerUser(this.newContactForm.getRawValue()).subscribe(({
        error: error => {
          let errorMessage = error.message;
          console.error('There was an error!', error);
        }
      }))
    }


registerUser(data: any)
  {
    return this.http.post<PersonenSharing[]>(this.pController,data);
  }
```

Backend POST:

```javascript
// POST: api/Personens
        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Personen>> PostPersonen(Personen personen)
        {
            _context.Personens.Add(personen);
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (PersonenExists(personen.PersonId))
                {
                    return Conflict();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return CreatedAtAction("GetPersonen", new { id = personen.PersonId }, personen);
        }
```

I tried it also without the personId into my FormControl. Then is my person id is - PersonId    {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  System.Guid

It seems like that it doesn't generate a new personId.

Comment: what is the value you are getting for `personId` in `console.log(this.newContactForm.getRawValue());` ..?

Comment: personId: null . I just tried to give it a "standard value" and thought it will generated itself in the backend. but now im not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is by configuring auto generation for GUID in the backend, there is nothing to do with GUIDs in front (you can send it in the request though, but that is not the case).

There are many solutions for this, I prefer to configure it by assigning new GUID through the constructor of Person model e.g.

```
Public class Person
{
  public Person()
  {
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
  }

  public string Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  .
  .
  .
}
```